# Annotation access modifier - public vs abstract

Tags: java

What is the difference between **public** and **abstract** modifier for an elements of **annotation** in Java.

For example we could use access modifier `public` for annotation element:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    public String element();// declared as public method
}
```

We also could use access modifier `abstract` for annotation element:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    abstract String element();// declared as abstract method
}
```

I thought that by default annotation methods are **abstract** and also **public**.

Then what is the actual impact of those modifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java **annotation** is a special type of **interface**. So it follows rules of interface and interface methods are by default `public` and `abstract`. In spite of default consideration, you could still add both `public` and `abstract` modifier explicitly. But it will be considered as ***redundant***.

Additionally if you declare a variable inside annotation, by default it will be a `final` and `static` variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no impact - it's just a redundant declaration. Same with interface's methods, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are redundant. As described in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html) the methods of an interface are [abstract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1.1) and public by default.

Answer (score 0):

Every `interface` is implicitly `abstract`. The interface implicitly declares a public `abstract` member method.

Answer (score 0):

An annotation type is a special kind of interface. In an interface, all methods are implicitly both public and abstract, but is allowed to explicitly state that a method is public and/or abstract. Declaring an interface method as public or abstract has no effect, however.